# Parsing Apple.Mail's *.elmx files [MIME messages]

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm in search of a framework, which allows to **parse *.elmx email files of Apple.Mail**.

Ultimately, I'd like to extract attachments from emails.

**Unfortunately, I'm not aware of such a framework. Are you?**

*PS:* For general parsing problems, [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com/) looks promising.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to parse Apple Mail's file and not talk to the Mail server? Explain your problem a little and someone might be able to give you alternate ideas?

Comment: @Devraj Yes, certainly. I need to scan a whole bunch of very old emails, which no longer live on a server. The contents of those emails isn't of interest, since it always is 'Find attached the ...'. I solely need save to attached PDFs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open-source solution written almost entirely in objective-c called Pantomime although probably dated.  [Here's the link](http://www.collaboration-world.com/cgi-bin/project/description.cgi?pid=3).

Comment: Hm, thx! Someone even ported Pantomime to XCode 3 - I know him ;-) http://www.justria.com/2011/02/08/pantomime-framework-packed-as-xcode-3-project/ I'm happy to accept your answer. But let's give a day for other hints...

Comment: Cool.  What caught my attention was the 3rd bullet: _A powerful API to work on all aspects of Message objects_.  With that in mind, I wouldn't be surprised if you could get a collection of attachments.  I'm sure a little digging is required, but the key is to find where it parses and implement a similar (if not the same) logic in your project.  Since it's open source, should be a snap!

Comment: Absolutely. While I 'ported' Pantomime to the then recent Xcode release, I wrote a small sample case, which composed emails. Too bad, that no one any longer maintains Pantomime. Should someone move it over to GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using AppleScript and Automator and integrate the AppleScript in your Cocoa app.

Similar example here, http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=95583

Comment: Hm, I always try to not use AppleScript - because is has such a 'funny' syntax ;-)